Trouble with foreign keys and SQL Server 2019
I'm having issues trying to set up foreign key relationships. I am trying to re-create the GitHub Employee database located here.
The code provided is for MySQL and I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v19.
This is the general foreign key relationship:

There are multiple tables that are using the Employee Number from the Employee table as a foreign key connection.
Code for creating the FK:
alter table dept_manager
    add constraint FK_DeptManager_Employee_EmpNo
        foreign key (emp_no) references employee(emp_no) 
            on delete cascade;

alter table dept_emp
    add constraint FK_DeptEmp_Employee_EmpNo
        foreign key (emp_no) references employee(emp_no) 
            on delete cascade;

Creating the first FK works fine (Dept_Manager -> Employee), but any subsequent attempts results in this error:

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_DeptEmp_Employee_EmpNo". The conflict occurred in database "employee", table "dbo.employee", column 'emp_no'

I know this worked when I was creating it in MySQL when I was first learning. I have no idea how to resolve this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

could you please clarify what you mean under "but any subsequent attempts give me the following error". Do you try to insert something in this table?

When I run the Code in the snippet above.  Creating the Constraint and Foreign Key in the Dept_Manager table works fine.  When I attempt to do the same thing (while keeping the Constraint name unique) for the Dept_Emp table I get the error I mentioned.

Most likely, there are already values in dept_emp.emp_no that do not exist in the referenced table  - in employee.emp_no. Fix these errors - after that, you should be able to create the FK

You need to provide a complete [mre] within the question, i.e. every statement you run until you hit the error. You can't expect us to try and replicate what you did from external resources and guess at what point you made an error

Thank you!  That was exactly the problem.  I had data loaded in some tables but not others.
